# In App Purchases in React-Native Expo?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm wondering if there is a way to implement in-app purchases in Expo for an app that I'm developing. As I researched online, I haven't found a clear answer.

Could anyone help Please?

Answer (score 4):

Currently you cannot do that by using `Expo v30`.

There is a feature request you can vote for: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/in-app-purchases

For now, you can only do that with detached Expo.

You can read more here:

- https://docs.expo.io/versions/v30.0.0/expokit/eject.html
- https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/why-not-expo
- https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/174